# Запрос на авторизацию срабатывает некорректно C#

Tags: c#, авторизация, httpwebrequest

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте http://sssr-rutracker.org. Только вот запрос на авторизацию срабатывает не всегда. Если пытаться подключиться к оригинальной версии сайта (без sssr-), то все работает более-менее сносно...
Что я делаю не так?

```
//Отправляем запрос на первое получение куков для дальнейшей авторизации
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("login_username=MYLOGIN&login_password=MYPASSWORD&login=%C2%F5%EE%E4");
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sssr-rutracker.org/forum/login.php");//Строка для Post-запроса
        var cc = new CookieContainer();
        WebReq.CookieContainer = cc;//включаем куки
        WebReq.Method = "POST";
        WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        HttpWebResponse WebResp;

        try
        {
            Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
            PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            PostData.Close();
            WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка сети", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        //Отправляем запрос к странице с торрентом для получения ее содержимого
        var url = URL.Text;
        WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebReq.CookieContainer = cc;
        WebReq.Method = "GET";
        WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

        string result;
        Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(WebResp.CharacterSet);
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(WebResp.GetResponseStream(), responseEncoding))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка сети", "Заголовок сообщения", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        //Скачать торрент

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            HD.LoadHtml(result);
            var match = HD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='dl-stub dl-link']").GetAttributeValue("href","");
            WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sssr-rutracker.org/forum/" + match.ToString());
            WebReq.CookieContainer = cc;
            WebReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            WebReq.Method = "POST";
            WebReq.Referer = url;
            WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            /*Пишем его в файл*/
            Stream ReceiveStream = WebReq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            string filename = @"D:\123.torrent";
            byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
            FileStream outFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = ReceiveStream.Read(buffer1, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                outFile.Write(buffer1, 0, bytesRead);
            outFile.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Файл загружен!");
            ReceiveStream.Close();
```

Comment: "Срабатывает не всегда" -- какое конкретно исключение вылетает? Напоминаю: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ***ошибку*** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Для того чтобы понять какая ошибка возникает нужно использовать переменную ошибки `catch (Exception ex)` и выводить в лог или сразу в окно описание ошибки: `ex.Message`, а не ставить тупые и молчаливые `catch` как у вас.

Comment: Ошибка вылезает при попытке получить содержимое для переменной match, тип искомый объект не найден. А найден он может быть лишь в том случае, если авторизация прошла успешно (класс, который я прописал в xpath-выражении, доступен лишь для авторизованных пользователей). Если просмотреть содержимое переменной result, то мы увидим исходный код страницы БЕЗ авторизации.

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что авторизация не проходит птмчт нужно ввести еще капчу (она иногда появляется, если заходишь на сайт через обычный браузер), однако я понятия не имею как проверить это и, если она действительно нужна, то как ее программно ввести.

Comment: Вообще то капчи как раз и придуманы для того, чтобы оградится от ботов и проч. программ.

Comment: А для этого нужно хотя бы залогировать результат ответа, чтобы понять - что пришло от сервера. А чтобы не мучиться с капчами, я бы предложил авторизоваться вручную, после чего работать под этой сессий, пошарив куки.

Comment: @LunarWhisper, а можно подробнее про "пошарив куки"? Что-то я не очень понял о чем речь)

Comment: `var cc = new CookieContainer();` вот здесь ты создаёшь пустой куки контейнер, в который будет помещён результат аутентификации. Я предлагаю установить сессию вручную посредством Web-браузера, а контейнер использовать общий. Пример можно найти тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185171/use-cookies-from-cookiecontainer-in-webbrowser